# How to avoid race condition in Windows Azure Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We have a Queue and multiple instances of same worker role reading the messages from the queue. The processing of each message is very fast. How do we avoid a case where two instances try to read same message from the queue at exact same point of time.

Comment: Have you actually seen this error, or is this hypothetical?

Comment: I haven't seen the error. Could not find any documentation in msdn saying this issue is handled in their service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not going to have any problems with multiple clients accessing an Azure Storage Queue simultaneously, provided you follow a Read-and-Delete pattern:

> The message is not automatically deleted from the queue, but after it has been retrieved, it is not visible to other clients for the time interval specified by the `visibilitytimeout` parameter.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179474.aspx

The nature of queues requires that every operation on the head of the queue must be atomic. In the case of queues as services, if it were possible for multiple clients to perform concurrent operations which caused overlapped reads, the queue would be utterly unusable.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Azure Queues support 2 mechanisms for reading messages from a queue - [`Get`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179474.aspx) and [`Peek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179472.aspx). To avoid race condition, recommendation would be to read the messages using `Get` mechanism as when you read the message using `Get`, the message becomes invisible to other callers (worker role instances in your case) for some amount of time thus only one instance will be able to read and process the message.

Comment: Our issue is different. Suppose we have two worker role instances P1 and P2 trying to read same message from Queue using a GET  at exact same point of time what happens in this case? If P1 Gets the message first then it will not be visible to others, but what if both P1 and P2 try to get same message?

Comment: So with Windows Azure Queues, you can't instruct the service which message to get. When you call Get Message, it returns the messages from the top of the queue. I haven't tried it myself but I'm assuming that even when two instances try to get the message at the same time, the service is built in such a way that same message is not made available to both instances.

Comment: That is correct. When Get Message is called, a specific message can only be received by one of the clients until it becomes visible again.